# SQL Server error '80040e14' incorrect syntax on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, sql-server-2008-r2

I am tasked with migrating a Classic ASP web application with SQL Server 2005 database from Windows Server 2003 (32bit) to Windows Server 2012 R2 with SQL Server 2012.

The code is very old and I don't want to do any code changes to make this workable in the above mentioned environment.

I have achieved almost all of the above but when testing the web application at a certain page where a report generation command is given the application breaks with error...

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'
>   Incorrect syntax near '*'.
>   D:\WEBSITES\XXXXXXXXX\REPORTS../common.asp, line 84

Following is the line 84 code:

```
rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
```

Strangely when I change the SQL Server from 2012 to SQL Server 2008 R2, the application works properly and generates the required report and displays in the browser.

I would also like to mention that this code/database combination works properly on Windows 2003(IIS6)/SQL Server 2005.

I have tried by changing the compatibility mode of SQL Server 2012 to SQL 2005 (90) but that has not helped.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual SQL statement being executed?

Comment: Yes, please show what is in the adCmdText at the time of execution.

Comment: `I have tried by changing the compatibility mode of SQL Server 2012 r2 to SQL 2005 (90) but that has not helped.` that has different purpose -- when you create SQL Script in Management studio it will be compatible with specific version of SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to the game, but I was receiving the same error number and was pulling my hair out to determine the cause.  It turned out to be one of my column names "Module" must be a keyword.  When I enclosed the Module name as so "[Module]", all worked fine.  So you might check to determine if one of the words in your code is now considered a keyword.  (I believe this might be the case as the newer version probably has more keywords.)

Comment: It happened to me for a table named system. I had to change its name.